# Django Select widget not updating in UpdateView

Tags: jquery, python, django

In my Django program, I have an UpdateView that takes an Event object (one of my models) and populates the form fields with the object's data. Everything works fine for the most part, including textboxes, datepicker fields, and autocomplete boxes. The one thing that consistently does not populate is my select field: a dropdown of available assistants. For some reason, it never updates and always goes to a blank choice.

**From views.py**, snippet from my UpdateView extending class

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SchedulerEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.request.user, initial={
        'hospital': self.object.hospital,
        'surgeon': self.object.surgeon,
        'procedure': self.object.procedure,
        'date': self.object.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),
        'patient': self.object.patient,
        'requested_assistant': 2, # Why won't this work??
        'insurance': self.object.insurance
```

As you can see, I tried setting everything manually, and I even tried just a static number that I knew was associated with a pk in the select field, in this case, 2.

**From event_form.html**, the part of the template relevant to the assistant part of the Event model:

```
<div class="row form-entry center">
   <span id="requested_assistant" class="">{{ form.requested_assistant }}</span>
</div>
```

And lastly, from the same file, the only other possible thing I can think of that is interfering:

```
    $('#id_requested_assistant').append('<option value="0"selected="selected" hidden>Requested Assistant</option>');
    $("#id_requested_assistant").change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
        else $(this).removeClass("empty")
    });
    $("#id_requested_assistant").change();
```

This snippet was designed to add a placeholder to the select box. It's an ugly workaround, but it seemed to work.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT: I tried a suggestion and changed views.py to this:**

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {'hospital': self.object.hospital,
            'surgeon': self.object.surgeon,
            'procedure': self.object.procedure,
            'date': self.object.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),
            'patient': self.object.patient,
            'requested_assistant_id': 2,  # Why won't this work??
            'insurance': self.object.insurance,
            }
```

Still no luck though

Comment: Using `requested_assistant_id` will probably work. Also note that you shouldn't really be overriding `get_context_data` here, but [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial), since all you're doing is providing custom initial data.

Comment: I tried that, and unless I goofed (I updated it above), it's still not working :(

Comment: Can you show the form and the model?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit me with a brick, it was that JavaScript snippet that messed me up. I switched my Select over to a jQuery Select2 widget so I could set a placeholder label; the only reason I needed that snippet in the first place.

Case closed!